# How did they get the standard form of this LP?

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

I'm confused to what method they are using to get the standard form of this LP? Why is there an "e" variable? I need help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's a surplus variable, the purpose is to convert the first inequality into an equality.

Notice that if $a \ge b$, it is equivalent to there exists an $e \ge 0$ such that $a-e = b$.

To see this, if $a \ge b$, we have $a-b \ge 0$, we then let $e=a-b$.

Conversely, if $e=a-b$ where $e \ge 0$, then we have $a-b \ge 0$.